# UIButton not responding to touches

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I've the following view:

[image]

The way it is build up

UIViewController --> UIView (bottom square) --> UIViewController (is loaded in the bottom square)

Button presses within in this UIViewController are not being triggered. However I do see the button animate when I press down in the simulator.

Also when I add the following tap handler programmatically to the round UIImageView in this UIViewController it responds:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        print("tappable")
    }

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NeighbourhoodViewController.handleTap(_:)))
userPopupView.userImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
userPopupView.userImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

How can I catch actions upon these buttons? This isn't working:

```
@IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("test")
    }
```

The line is connected to the UIButton in interface builder btw:

[image]

Comment: User interaction enabled on the button or view in question?

Comment: Yep, user interaction enabled every where. On the UIView. On the UIViewController. On the UIButton. Button also animates (it is being highlighted and such when pressed) indicating a touch is received.

Comment: Is this "test" method the only thing linked to that buttons outlets?  Take a look at the outlets tab in the IB to confirm nothing is conflicting.

Comment: Added another image.

Comment: I got nothing... will be interested to know the solution to this.

Comment: Found out that pushing the buttons results in a crash on iOS 8.1. Maybe this extra piece of info will aid in finding the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I just had this to add the ViewController to the View:

```
self.popupView.addSubview(userPopupView.view)
```

When it should have been:

```
self.addChildViewController(userPopupView)
self.popupView.addSubview(userPopupView.view)
userPopupView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Now it works!

Comment: Still not right. The dance is: `addChildViewController`; `addSubview`; `didMoveToParentViewController` - in that order. Do that and no other. There are strict rules about this.

Comment: Thanks matt! I've adjusted my answer.